# How to remove vertical space between the last line and the body of table?

Tags: tables

How to remove the vertical space between item2 and the last line?

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}
\maketitle
\begin{tabular}{p{8cm}}
\hline
\textbf{Algorithm 1} \\
\hline
\begin{enumerate}[1:]
\item item1
\item item2
\end{enumerate}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could switch from `enumerate` to [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) and kill the vertical spacing of the `enumerate`; using the optional argument for `\\` you can fine tune the vertical separation of the bottom rule. However, consider using some dedicated package, such as [`algorithmicx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem), for your algorithms (I included an example taken from the documentation for `algpseudocode`); manual numbering and formatting elements is not a good practice (you won't have easy cross-reference capabilities and the manual approach is error-prone):

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\noindent\begin{tabular}{p{8cm}}
\hline
\textbf{Algorithm 1} \\
\hline
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*:,nolistsep]
\item item1
\item item2
\end{enumerate}\\[-2ex]
\hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Euclid’s algorithm}\label{euclid}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
\State $r\gets a\bmod b$
\While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
\State $a\gets b$
\State $b\gets r$
\State $r\gets a\bmod b$
\EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
\State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]